# Azure storage Services

Tags: c#, azure

How do you create a blob or tables in using Azure storage services?. 
    I have created the Azure storage account. below is the code I have written using c#.

```
    private CloudBlobContainer GetCloudBlobContainer()
    {
       // this is the storage account connection string created

        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
                CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("<storageaccountname>_AzureStorageConnectionString"));
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("test-blob-container");
        return container;
```

I have created the storage account and now the connection string, so how do I proceed from here?

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is to call the [**`CreateIfNotExist()`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.createifnotexists?view=azure-dotnet) method on the container to create it:

```
container.CreateIfNotExist();
```